# Oracle find date and new the new change in a column value for a set of specific business keys

Tags: oracle, primary-key

I have a set of columns and I would like to know the change in a column for different dates.

Ex:

```
|account |type| open_date, |p_code| biz_date   |
|:------:|:--:|:----------:|:----:|:----------:|
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | AA   | 31-jan-20  |
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | AA   |  28-feb-20 |
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | BB   |  31-mar-20 |
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | BB   |  30-apr-20 |
```

**Desired Result:**

```
|account |type| open_date, |p_code| biz_date   |
|:------:|:--:|:----------:|:----:|:----------:|
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | AA   | 31-jan-20  |
|  1     | A  | 20-jan-17  | BB   |  31-mar-20 |
```

The p_code changed from AA --> BB on 31-mar-20.

So I would like to know the change in p_code values over different business_date for a specified set of account, type,open_Date combination.
( account, type and open_Date are primary keys)

Comment: Please learn to format your posts (the code, especially). Read this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks and practice by editing your post and formatting it. I won't read your question till you do, and I hope no one else will either.

Comment: Is this better now?

Comment: Much bitter, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this - using the `lag()` analytic function to flag out the change rows in a subquery. I used the most efficient way - I give them a `null` flag, while the non-change rows get the flag `0`. (Alas, analytic functions are calculated **after** the `where` clause filters are applied - which means you need an outer query to select what you need.)

I assumed your table name is `sample_data` - change that as needed.

```
select account, type, open_date, p_code, biz_date
from   (
         select account, type, open_date, p_code, biz_date, 
                case when p_code = lag(p_code) 
                       over (partition by account, type, open_date order by biz_date)
                     then 0 end as change
         from   sample_data
       )
where  change is null
;
```